# Is this a correct JSON string?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am not quite clear on how to make a JSON string. I get error and I want to find out how to correct and it make it.

This is my JSON string:

```
var drivers = { "driver" : [
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "name" : "Bob",
        "age" : "34"
        "car" : [
            {
                "make" : "BMW",
                "model" : "3.20",
                "colour" : "Silver"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "name" : "Rob",
        "age" : "22"
        "car" : [
            {
                "make" : "Peugeot",
                "model" : "306",
                "colour" : "Blue"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id" : 3,
        "name" : "Maria",
        "age" : "23",
        "car" : [
            {
                "make" : "Mazda",
                "model" : "3",
                "colour" : "Red"
            }
        ]
    }]};
```

This is the get method:

```
var driverData = JSON.parse(drivers);

function getDriverData() {
    return driverData;
}

return {
    getDriverData: getDriverData
};
```

And in this controller I try to get it so I can see if it works:

```
var drivers = myDriveApi.getDriverData();
console.log(driverData);
```

Correct me and explain how to make a JSON string, and I want it nested if that's the right term. So each driver has a car, or multiple cars/vehicles. So if I get 1 driver, I want to see his details and his information on owned vehicles.

Comment: Try using http://jsonlint.com :)

Comment: If it is an object to start, why are you parsing it?

Comment: That's not a "JSON string" it's a JavaScript object.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: there are missing commas between "age" and "car" in multiple places

Comment: JSON is a data serialization used for transferring data between environments, much like XML. If the data hard coded into your application as native object types, it isn't JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "JSON string" seems to be JavaScript code that you would have in a script tag that creates a `drivers` JavaScript object with a property called `driver` that is an array of other objects. To be JSON, you remove the `var drivers =` and the semicolon at the end leaving just what you would set a variable to in order to create that object.

For instance, let's say you have a "person" variable that is an object with "firstName" and "lastName" properties.  This is code you would put into a script to create that variable:

```
var person = { firstName: "Jason", lastName: "Goemaat" };
```

Strings, even JSON strings are represented in scripts surrounded by single or double quotes.  To see the string value for the JSON of that object, you can do this:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(person);
```

This gives you a valid JSON string which will display this in the console:

```
{"firstName":"Jason","lastName":"Goemaat"}
```

To set the variable directly you need to enclose it in single or double quotes, but if the string contains those they would need to be escaped.  Since this contains only double quotes I will surround it in single quotes to assign it to a variable in my script, then parse that into an object.

```
var json = '{"firstName":"Jason","lastName":"Goemaat"}';
var person = JSON.parse(json);
```

JSON property names need to be surrounded in quotes.  Most parsers will work if they are not but it is always better to be as correct as you can be.  You can use the online tool at [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) to check for valid JSON.

Comment: Thanks, that helped out a lot to help me understand JSON. Especially with the help of console being able to convert js objects to JSON, that is just amazing.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's a JavaScript object, which could be converted to a JSON string using `JSON.stringify(object)`.

If you're trying to access it through JavaScript, you might as well skip JSON altogether and just use the object. If you want to test if a JSON string is good, use jsonlint.com.

Answer (score 0):

1. It's a JavaScript object, not a JSON string.
2. You're missing commas after Bob and Rob's age. Maria's all good, though.